# Step-by-step re-arranging of a string with randomized characters

Tags: algorithm, c, strings, random

A sloppy code featuring algorithms to efficiently randomize the characters of a string "Hello C" and then print out in the console the re-arrangement process for every character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
    char    characters[8]   = "Hello C"; /* Keeps track of used characters   */
    int     iCharacters     = 7;        /* Number of unused characters      */
    char    scrambled[8]    = {'\0'};   /* First scrambled string           */
    int     orders[8]       = {0};      /* Table of initial positions       */
    int     initOrders[8]   = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    /* Scramble */
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        int     rn  = rand() % iCharacters;
        char    ch  = characters[rn];
        
        --iCharacters;
        
        /* Interpolation */
        orders[i]       = initOrders[rn];
        initOrders[rn]  = initOrders[iCharacters];
        
        /* Update list of used characters and scrambled string */
        characters[rn]  = characters[iCharacters];
        scrambled[i]    = ch;
    }
            
    /* Auto re-arrange */
    char revision[8] = {'\0'};
    strcpy(revision, scrambled);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        int correctOrder = orders[i];
        
        if(correctOrder > i)
        {
            for(int ip = i; ip <= correctOrder; ip++)
            {
                char temp[8] = {'\0'};

                strcpy(temp, revision);
                
                temp[ip] = revision[i];
                
                printf("%s\n", temp);
            }
        }
        else if(correctOrder < i)
        {
            for(int in = i; in >= correctOrder; in--)
            {
                char temp[8] = {'\0'};

                strcpy(temp, revision);
                
                temp[in] = revision[i];
                
                printf("%s\n", temp);
            }
        }
        
        /* Puts scrambled[i] where it belongs */
        revision[correctOrder] = scrambled[i];
        
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0x0;
}
```

---

If the randomized string is  `lelCoH`, the output should be as follow:

```
 lelCoH
  elCoH
 l lCoH
 le CoH
 lel oH
 lelC H

 lelC H
 lllC H
 lelC H

 lelC H
 eelC H

 eelC H
 ellC H

 ellC H
 ellCCH
 ellC C

 ellC C
 ell  C

 ello C
 elloCC
 ellC C
 elCo C
 eClo C
 Cllo C
Cello C

Hello C
Hello 
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
```

Notice how each characters get moved by one position until it reaches the initial position.
The loop can be changed to `for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)` to prevent the last paragraph operation from happening. This code can be optimized for memory and efficiency, and there might be redundant code too. Additionally, it can be further improved by wrapping everything up in a function where you can conveniently pass any string. Note that you can achieve similar progressive re-arrangement with much fewer operations by using something like the Damerau–Levenshtein distance algorithm, but the effect of "smooth transition" becomes less evident.

Answer (score 6):

**Proper randomization?**

Given `" lelCoH"`, how is output `" elloCC"` a proper re-arrangement?

**Candidate scramble alternative**

```
// Unchecked code
#define N 7
char consumable_copy[N+1];
strcpy(consumable_copy, characters);

char scrambled[N+1];
for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
  int rand_index = rand()%(N-i);
  scrambled[i] = consumable_copy[rand_index];
  consumable_copy[rand_index] = consumable_copy[N-i];
}
scrambled[N] = '\0';
```

**Clearer output**

Printed output lacks clarity concerning white-space.  Either surround with sentinels like `<` and `>` or use an example strings with all non-empty graphical output like `"abcdefg"`.

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Replace those `8`s with `N` using something like `#define N 8`.

**Minor: Simplify**

Why hex with `return 0x0;`?

Consider `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Answer (score 4):

**Avoid magic numbers:**

```
    char    characters[8]   = "Hello C"; /* Keeps track of used characters   */
    int     iCharacters     = 7;        /* Number of unused characters      */
    char    scrambled[8]    = {'\0'};   /* First scrambled string           */
    int     orders[8]       = {0};      /* Table of initial positions       */
    int     initOrders[8]   = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    /* Scramble */
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

I'd suggest defining a macro for 8 - or use C23's `constexpr` - and use `sizeof` to determine `icharacters`.

**Inconsistent formatting:**

At times there's a blank line after each statement, at times there is none. Consider using an auto-formatter (GNU Indent or the like).

**Minor:**

```
printf("%s\n", temp);
```

There's no need to use `printf()` for this. Use `puts()`.

And `return 0x0` is very unusual. Use the octal constant 0, or `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Good compilers emit efficient code for either `printf("%s\n", temp);` and `puts(temp);`.  I recommend to use whatever is most clear for the overall block of code.

Answer (score 4):

`rand()` is quite slow on modern GNU/Linux compared to a good modern PRNG.  The Glibc implementation takes/releases a lock even in a single-threaded program.  (To see this, compile a program like `int main(){return rand();}` with `gcc -g -fno-plt` and `stepi` into the `call rand` in GDB.)

Internally, Glibc `rand()` calls `random()`, which takes a lock and then calls `random_r()` on seed shared between all threads.  The locking doesn't special-case for programs that haven't been linked with `libpthread`, so despite the PRNG being pretty simple, it's not fast either.

If you care at all about speed in a program that needs a lot of random numbers, either use your own PRNG (like [xoroshiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xoshiro)), or use [`random_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random_r.3.html) with your own state variable, although the API for initializing it is not ideal as the man page notes.  Or there's `long mrand48()` which in glibc avoids taking a lock, which returns a value in `[-2^31, +2^31)` (signed int32_t), although its not the best PRNG.

Comment: Yeah it was a 2 minute code for a discord bot that compiles and runs code snippets.
In a real world scenario I would either use mtwister, or Glib's own randomization functions, which are probably system-specific wrappers in which case it'll actually end up being even slower. Also, native `rand()` is pretty efficient actually, just not when used with the modulo operator.

Comment: @Edenia: `rand()` is *not* very efficient, see [Why do fast memory writes when run over multiple threads take much more time vs when they are run on a single thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78030661) for an example.  Even in a single-threaded program it's slow, but with contention between threads it's far worse.